# Typescript event prevent Default not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want the following a tag to not refresh the page every time I click it but regardless what I do, it still does.

```
              <p>
                <a
                  onClick={(e) => handleClick}
                  href=""
                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                >
                  &lt;Return to cart
                </a>
              </p>
```

This is my handleClick:

```
  const handleClick = (e: React.ChangeEvent<EventTarget>): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    closeForm();
  };
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

I tried looking up older answers like the one I have above but they don't seem to work. My app won't work unless I figure this out because it'll refresh the user's cart, which is obviously a big problem. Is it wrong to use an a tag and just use a button instead? Or is my type wrong for the event?

Comment: Hello! Can you show whole component?

Comment: You never call your function. Should be `onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>
     <a
       onClick={(e) => handleClick} // <--- you're not calling handleClick
       href=""
       style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
     >
       &lt;Return to cart
     </a>
  </p>
```

Instead, do this:

```
<p>
   <a
      onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)} // <--- call handleClick, passing e to it
      href=""
      style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
    >
      &lt;Return to cart
    </a>
 </p>
```

Or if you want to do it more elegantly :

```
onClick={handleClick}
```

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!